# What exception to throw when trying to remove an element from an empty LinkedList?

Tags: java

I'm thinking IndexOutOfBoundsException, but that doesn't sound that intuitive to me but it might be the right one?

Edit: i'm trying to implement my own linkedlist methods, not array. And I'm trying to call remove() on a linkedlist.

Comment: are you sure that the JVM will not throw an exception if you dont?

Comment: what u tried so far ?

Comment: I tried IndexOutOfBoundsException but I can always change it to another exception and it will throw that exception, right?

Comment: Java will do it for you. You don't have to worry about such trivial things.

Comment: @WhoAmI I'm asking whether I should throw IndexOutOfBoundsException, or perhaps something else like NullPointerException since the LinkedList is empty?

Comment: I think a fooBarException is just about right.

Comment: You should throw your application specific exception MyException

Comment: @B.A. You should either rethrow `NoSuchElementException` (if you are catching it). Throwing custom exception totally depend on your requirement. But, if you want to throw some specific version of `NoSuchElementException`, then why not make a custom exception that is subclass of `NoSuchElementException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use java.util.NoSuchElementException to be consistent with JCF, remove() with no arg is java.util.Queue method and Queue.remove() throws NoSuchElementException - if this queue is empty

Answer (score 1):

Documentation: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove%28%29)

It throws:

```
NoSuchElementException
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own exception and provide business specific message to that exception.